# SlidingUpPanelLayout conflicting with Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

I have a project that uses the `SlidingUpPanelLayout` but I needed to start writing automated tests using Robolectric. When I introduced Robolectric to the project my Espresso based tests failed to start up. I would get an `java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation` when the system would try and inflate the SlidingUpPanelLayout.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.marcthomas.testrobolectric/com.marcthomas.testrobolectric.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
    at com.marcthomas.testrobolectric.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:14)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(GoogleInstrumentation.java:428)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    ... 11 more
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
    ... 23 more
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
    at com.sothree.slidinguppanel.ViewDragHelper.<init>(ViewDragHelper.java:392)
    at com.sothree.slidinguppanel.ViewDragHelper.create(ViewDragHelper.java:348)
    at com.sothree.slidinguppanel.ViewDragHelper.create(ViewDragHelper.java:361)
    at com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.<init>(SlidingUpPanelLayout.java:334)
    at com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.<init>(SlidingUpPanelLayout.java:263)
    ... 26 more
```

If I remove the SlidingUpPanelLayout from my `activity_my.xml` layout file in the project the tests will run successfully again, so it does seem to be something to do with these two components somehow.

I have created a demo project on github that demonstrates this behaviour. Cloning the code and running `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest` will reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I needed to add

```
exclude module: 'support-v4'
```

to the list of excludes in the app module gradle file where androidTestCompile for robolectric is declared. See explanation below.

---

This error was down to a Gradle configuration error. The reason is that there are dependencies declared multiple times in the build and one of them needs to be excluded.

To work this out look at the last part of the exception.

ViewDragHelper was the culprit so if in your IDE (Android Studio) open the search for class name (Command-O in OS X) and enter ViewDragHelper. You will see that there are multiple Jars that are returned. You will need to exclude the one that you don’t want.

In this situation we had the `android-19` sdk, `support-v4-19` and `support-v4-20` and `library-2.0.1` (the slideuppanellayout library) to solve this I needed to `exclude support-v4`.

So in the build gradle file for the project where I included robolectric I needed to add the following to the list of excludes.

`exclude module: 'support-v4'`